# progress dialog not showing in android?

Tags: android, progressdialog

when does the progress dialog not show in android? i want to know the circumstances when the above can happen:

in my case the progress dialog was not showing in this case:

```
func{
    progressdialog.show();
    ....
    .....
    anotherfunction();
    listview.setAdapter();
    progressdialog.dismiss();
   }
```

what is the general rule of thumb with dialog boxes?

thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
when the .show() command is executed the progress dialog should show. But when the otherfucntion() is called, does the previous command of progressdialog show stop?

Comment: What thread was executing that code? Did you get any error messages in the log? How was the progressdialog created?

Comment: i am executing it in the main UI thread. i did not get an error messages, just the progress dialog never showed up, the statements after it started execution... and finished successfully without the progress dialog  being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) the UI (including the progressDialog) will not update if the UI thread is still busy. There are many examples in SO for that.

And as a rule of thumb - **if you need Progress dialog - you need AsyncTask**.

It is not that any command stops, it is just that if you execute a sequence of methods on the UI thread, the UI will probably not be updated until the sequence is over, which is after `progressDialog.dismiss()`, so the progressDialog should not be displayed anymore.

Comment: but if i am updating the UI like populating a listview then?

Comment: Do what you can in background (like acquiring data from DB / web / contacts / etc.), just the final part in UI thread. Please read the AsyncTask documentation (see link in my answer), I'm sure you'll find that helpful.

Comment: and when does the ui thread become *too* busy? does this mean that if i have less amount of fuctions in my UI thread i can use the progress dialog in the UI thread? what is actually happening?

Comment: If you are executing a sequence of methods (like in your example) on the UI thread, the UI itself won't be updated until all the method in the sequence are finished executed, if you run most of it on a background thread, and only polls the UI thread when there's a change, the UI thread will be updated during the execution.

Comment: so in general, even if i have a small number of functions, i should use a separate thread so that the UI thread is free to show a progress dialog?

Comment: If those methods takes time or if they are heavy, than yes. It's a pain at first, but it becomes easier as soon as you catch the concept.

Comment: How to get result from a async thread, i mean if my thread is populating a listview, how do i know that it is complete. there is a method called onPostExecution but how do i let my activity know that a task is complete?   Also if i am waiting for an array to be populated by async task, how do i know when the array is populated?

Comment: also i find using a handler as shown in the answer below much handy as compared to using a AsyncTask.

Comment: This is your choice, but AsyncTask was built to make such tasks easier to implement.

Comment: How to get result from a async thread, i mean if my thread is populating a listview, how do i know that it is complete. there is a method called onPostExecution but how do i let my activity know that a task is complete? Also if i am waiting for an array to be populated by async task, how do i know when the array is populated?

Comment: onPostExecution is called once the task is completed. I cannot tell you much without seeing your code (and unfortunately, I won't have time to look at it today anyway) look for examples of AsyncTask usage, there are plenty.

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to do this in your activity.

```
ProgressDialog _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Saving Data","Please wait......");
settintAdater();

 private void settingAdater(){

        Thread _thread = new Thread(){

            public void run() {

                Message _msg = new Message();
                _msg.what = 1; 
                 // Do your task where you want to rerieve data to set in adapet
                YourCalss.this._handle.sendMessage(_msg);
            };
        };
        _thread.start();
    }
 Handler _handle = new Handler(){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch(msg.what){

                case 1:
                    _progressDialog.dismiss();
                     listview.setAdapter();
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: correct, i used to do this before. but i wanted to know when to do this?- when there are a lot of functions in my UI thread , or even when there a small number of functions?

Comment: You can use Handler in any case because you just need to create a Thread for background operation and a Handler to handle all the background operation in your Activity . In AsynTask you have to create separate class for each operation so it is not handy.

Answer (score 0):

To show a ProgressDialog use

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PrintMain.this, "", 
                    "Uploading Document. Please wait...", true);
```

And when you have completed your task use

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

to dismiss the ProgressDialog ..

You can call to show the ProgressDialog in your `onPreExecute` method  of `AsyncTask` class and when your done dismiss it in the `onPostExecute` method